# How to detect touch outside of our app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, permissions, touch, wallpaper

I want to detect the touch of home screen(where wallpaper is set)
Want to create a live wallpaper app for that i need to detect home screen touch.
On tapping outside the i get the gesture and apply onpressed function as well